# How to not combine images of multiple galleries with colorbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, gallery, colorbox

Need your expert help/advice on this colorbox usage issue.

I have a set of galleries to be displayed on a screen, where each gallery is triggered by a click on the displayed album's pic. The problem is that it is combining the images of all three galleries appeared on the same screen and showing all images in each album's view. 
 Tried with changing the 'rel' attribute for each album's trigger, but still I could not make it work.

Say the code looks like:

```
var rel = $(this).attr('rel');

$(".album_view").colorbox({
   rel: rel,
   maxWidth: "800px",
   maxHeight: "600px",
   width: "auto",
   height: "auto"
});
```

and in the html, it looks like:

```
<a  href="https://www.website.com/album/folder1/image1.jpg" class="album_view" rel="album_view_1024" target="album_post_1024" ><img src="https://www.website.com/album/folder1/image1.jpg" width="464"  height="261" /></a>
<a  href="https://www.website.com/album/folder1/image2.jpg" class="album_view" rel="album_view_1024" target="album_post_1024" ></a>
<a  href="https://www.website.com/album/folder1/image3.jpg" class="album_view" rel="album_view_1024" target="album_post_1024" ></a>
<a  href="https://www.website.com/album/folder1/image4.jpg" class="album_view" rel="album_view_1024" target="album_post_1024" ></a>
...
...
...
<a  href="https://www.website.com/album/folder2/image1.jpg" class="album_view" rel="album_view_2324" target="album_post_2324" ><img src="https://www.website.com/album/folder2/image1.jpg" width="464"  height="261" /></a>
<a  href="https://www.website.com/album/folder2/image2.jpg" class="album_view" rel="album_view_2324" target="album_post_2324" ></a>
<a  href="https://www.website.com/album/folder2/image3.jpg" class="album_view" rel="album_view_2324" target="album_post_2324" ></a>
...
...
...
```

As you see it there, only the first image of album is showed and its following are just to load for (for rel) to the slide show. 
But, if I click on first album or second album, it is showing all 7 images (4+3 of 2 albums) up in each album show :(

Tried to change the 'rel' through the param as above, but it did not work.

What am I missing here? I am not a pro with this though. Please help. 
Any tip/advice/example would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: Sept 15, 2017. Added the following:**

Here is the script that would be invoked when clicked/loaded on an album.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://www.XYZsite.com/css/photo_gallery.css" />
<script 
src="https://www.XYZsite.com/js/gallery_js/photo_gallery_jquery.js">
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".image_view").colorbox({rel:'nofollow', maxWidth:"800px", maxHeight:"600px", width:"auto", height:"auto"});
    $('.image_view').click(function(e){
        //alert($(this).attr('title'));
        $('#popup_title').html($(this).attr('title'));
        $('#popup_content').html($(this).attr('content'));
    });

    $(".album_view").colorbox({maxWidth:"100%", maxHeight:"600px", width:"auto", height:"auto", current:"{current}/{total}"});
    $('.album_view').click(function(e){
        $('#popup_title').html($(this).attr('title'));
        $('#popup_content').html($(this).attr('content'));
    });
});
```

And in the later code, if any album is posted then it should display the first image on the screen and invoke the color to display the rest. (Following one has 2 test images)

```
<div id="album_post_1156" style="margin-top:8px;" class="bulletin_message_pic l hide_post1156" style="">
<a href="https://www.XYZsite.com/album/e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5/ea5d2f1c4608232e07d3aa3d998e5135/c1-jpg_071724.jpg" class="album_view" rel="album_view" ><img src="https://www.XYZsite.com/album/e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5/ea5d2f1c4608232e07d3aa3d998e5135/c1-jpg_071724.jpg" width="400" height="300" /></a>
<a href="https://www.XYZsite.com/album/e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5/ea5d2f1c4608232e07d3aa3d998e5135/c2-jpg_071721.jpg" class="album_view" rel="album_view"  title="Pic title"></a>
</div>
```

On the same page, there is another album post which has 4 test images in it. It calls the same above colorbox script with same "rel" group as:

```
<div id="album_post_1024" style="margin-top:8px;" class="bulletin_message_pic l hide_post1024" style="">
<a href="https://www.XYZsite.com/album/e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5/c9f0f895fb98ab9159f51fd0297e236d/p02gsc0n.jpg" class="album_view" rel="album_view" ><img src="https://www.XYZsite.com/album/e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5/c9f0f895fb98ab9159f51fd0297e236d/p02gsc0n.jpg" width="464" height="261" /></a>
<a href="https://www.XYZsite.com/album/e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5/c9f0f895fb98ab9159f51fd0297e236d/s0775904_sc7.jpg" class="album_view" rel="album_view"  title="Pic title"></a>
<a href="https://www.XYZsite.com/album/e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5/c9f0f895fb98ab9159f51fd0297e236d/tc32lew56_large.jpg" class="album_view" rel="album_view"  title="Pic title"></a>
<a href="https://www.XYZsite.com/album/e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5/c9f0f895fb98ab9159f51fd0297e236d/tcl60e55_large.jpg" class="album_view" rel="album_view"  title="Pic title"></a>
</div>
```

So, the problem is if I click on the first album's image or second album's image, it shows all (2+4) 6 images (from both the albums) together in the same colorbox window one after, where it should only show the images of that particular album.

And also, it is not even showing the image window as per the image's actual width/height automatically, rather it is showing all in one size width/height :(

What am I missing here? are the "rel" and "auto" attributes set to wrong or something else?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your anchor elements already have a rel attribute, so there is no need to pass anything to Colorbox.  Try replacing your code with this:

```
$(".album_view").colorbox({
   maxWidth: "800px",
   maxHeight: "600px",
   width: "auto",
   height: "auto"
});
```

You were replacing the anchor element's rel value by passing Colorbox some constant value got that applied to every '.album_view' element.  I'm not sure what your rel variable value was without knowing what 'this' was, but that is why everything was getting grouped together.

Comment: The 'rel' attribute to specify the group of pics to be showed as one album. As it shown in the post, first group of items are passed with album-id like 
 rel=''album_view_1024" and second group with rel="album_view_2324".  So, the rel value is passed into colorbox script and make the colorbox to generate a slideshow with the related pics.   I tried your suggestion removing the 'rel' in the .album_view script. Still it is showing all albums pics in each slide show :(